# How to request a delta using Microsoft.Graph C# API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-intune

In the following code, `GraphService` is a `GraphServiceClient` instance that is already connected, and the value returned into `foo` is a collection of Intune devices.

```cs
var foo = GraphService.Devices.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

As is, this gets *all* devices. Best practice documentation suggests use of a delta query as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview but Intellisense is not reporting a chainable `Delta()` method on `IGraphServiceDevicesCollectionRequestBuilder` (the type of `Devices`) or `IGraphServiceDevicesCollectionRequest` (returned by `Request()`)
 and I have yet to find any documentation for anything but the REST URLs.

How is one supposed to make a delta request using this library?

The request URL is surfaced as a mutable string property. Should I hack the URL to include "/delta" or is there a recommended way in documentation I have yet to read?

The Request method can take a parameter `IEnumerable<Option> options` but I have yet to find documentation of supported options so it's hard to know whether this is relevant.